# find_by_sql with array format in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model, find-by-sql

good day guys!

I'm using **find_by_sql()** in rails 3 to fetch records as follows.

```
@list=Email.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM Emails WHERE sent_id=?",params[:id]])
```

How to modify the same statement if multiple parameter applies for same attribute, say for example :

```
@list=Email.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM Emails WHERE (sent_id=? OR from_id=?)",params[:id],params[:id]])
```

Here, both **sent_id** and **from_id** attributes receives same parameter **params[:id]**

So, instead of passing same **params[:id]** twice, is there any mechanism available to pass parameter based on order?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use a hash to name the interpolated values, like this:

```
@list = Email.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM Emails WHERE (sent_id = :id OR from_id = :id)", {:id => params[:id]}])
```