# Parameterized queries with Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to execute some hand-hacked SQL through `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`, but for readability and protection against injection, I would like to use placeholders like in this old example: [find_by_sql with array format in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977104/find-by-sql-with-array-format-in-rails-3) instead of raw string interpolation.

None of the methods I have found on ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter which is the underlying class for `connection` appears to support this kind of behavior.

So how can do it? I want the result to be an area of hashes and I don't need to mix it with any existing ActiveRecord scopes.

Comment: Hey @NielsB! Did you find a better solution?

Comment: Nope, but based on EugZols solution, it may be possible to write a wrapper class that substitute *symbols* with escaped input. Maybe i'll give it a shot when I come back to it.

Answer (score -2):

Yep, looks like placeholders is out of option. I used manual escaping when faced the same problem:

```
user_id = user_id.to_i
client = connection.quote(client.to_s)

connection.execute(
  "INSERT INTO stats (user_id, client) VALUES (#{user_id}, #{client})"
)
```